# Website open in single window

Tags: javascript, jquery, tabs, popup, window

Is it possible to make my website url always open in single window where if user even try to run url in tab then my website automatically redirect and open in single popup wimdow.?

Please share your idea and help how I do this if it is possible thank u all.

Comment: Why would you want to do this? Sounds like horrible UX.

Comment: I don't understand UX. But I like to make as I understand it is secure and session save in single windows.

Comment: Nothing about a single window is more secure than multiple windows.  This sounds like an XY problem around an application not handling multiple user windows properly.

Comment: All browser windows and tabs share the same context and incognito windows share another.

Comment: I want , let consider if you click button then open popup wimdow which have not option to add tabs, single address bar, not option for right side 3 dotted options and etc

Comment: No, If make session start in new popup window then 100 % as I think that if user close the session  wimdow then session end and the single window not share session in tabs becouse it open in a new popup window and session is started from there

Comment: You could have a home page and then ajax in all your content when links are clicked, so you actually don't have any other pages and user has to start on home page, but as others have said this would be awful and not very good for seo

Comment: What if I open your page in Chrome and then open it in IE?  IE has 'new session' option (file menu).

Comment: Is it possible if I make single window , when success  login done session start in single popup window. it protect DDos attack becouse my login session in window where not options for add other tab and all session save in one window. What u think

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer is no.

It's not logical or reasonable. 
You can't control browser but you can control another page in your website to have fixed height and width in a new pop up browser control.

onClick="window.open('yourpage.htm',' pagename','resizable,height=260,width=370'); return false;"

Comment: It good but how I make it user direct copy your url `yourpage.htm` and paste run in normal chrome address bar. How I prevent it requires to open this url in a new window

Comment: Then it's better you don't use web based. That is, you should build a desktop application which load your website anytime users launch it. You can't control a browser that you didn't build to do what you're asking.

Comment: Ok thank you! Tell is it good when login success then next all pages open in wimdow. Why? Becouse login session save in wimdow and if user close wimdow session close and also no body can hack and attack DDos becouse the login session save in single window

Comment: If you believe a "single window" would stop hacking or DDOS (or even slightly slow it down), then you need to learn **a lot** more about the internet.